# Что значит в generic where T : unmanaged?

Tags: c#, .net

Сидел пробовал написать Generic метод для получения значения типа из указателя, и вот случайно написал `where T : unmanaged` и этот код был успешно откомпилирован!

Т.е. это дело выглядит вот так:

```
private static T ReadT<T>(IntPtr address, int offset) where T : unmanaged
{
    unsafe
    {
        return *(T*)IntPtr.Add(address, offset).ToPointer();
    }
}
```

Как это понимать? Что значит `unmanaged`?

Comment: Офдока: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: Т.е. тут все нормально и данный код валиден?

Comment: where T : unmanaged  Аргумент типа не может быть ссылочным типом и содержать члены ссылочного типа на любом уровне вложения. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: @LLENN: с чего бы нет?)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Ну если например туда структуру передать?

Comment: @LLENN: так как `unmanaged` и требует структуру - то все будет нормально. Как уже написали выше, структуру не обычную, а ту, у которой и все поля (на всех уровнях вложенности) также структуры. А ничего иного в метод Вы передать и не сможете, так как на метод (точнее, на generic-тип) вешается `IsUnmanaged`-атрибут, который заставляет компилятор проверять, что Вы туда пихаете